# How do you enable array extensions?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I can create a new VS2013 vb.net project with the following code, which compiles and runs fine:

```
Dim ii(12) As Integer
If ii.Contains(5) Then
...
End If
```

I have just converted a VS2008 vb.net project to VS2013. When I add code with the array extensions `.Contains` and `.ToList`, it causes a compile error "'Contains' [or 'ToList'] is not a member of 'System.Array'".

The "Imports" and References are identical between the projects, and I don't see any relevant difference in the project Properties. Is there a way to enable these array extensions?

Comment: Make sure target framework in project properties is .NET 3.5 or above.

Comment: Target framework in both projects is 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need .NET 3.5+, and a reference to `System.Linq` to get the extension method. (`Imports` is not necessary.)

You say that when you compare both projects, you don't see any differences in the "Imports" and References.

Perhaps, the difference is that your working project is implicitly importing `System.Linq`, and that's why you don't notice a difference.

Go to your working project, and go to `My Project`. Go to the `References` section, and have a look under `Imported namespaces`.  You'll probably find that `System.Linq` is checked in your working project, but not so in the project that doesn't work.

Comment: You're right. Even in a new, empty vb.net desktop project in VS2013, System.Linq is implicitly imported. Thanks!